# Library not found errors when trying to add a test project to Android via cmake using the documentaion instructions

Tags: android, cmake

I would like to add a test project that uses cmake to the main cmake for my Android app.

I have followed the instructions here
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake#include-other-cmake-projects
but get library not found errors. The page makes it sound like this should include the project without any issues.

I literally copied pasted the code and changed the file paths and variable names.

```
set( test_DIR ../../test/cpp)

# Sets lib_build_DIR to the path of the desired output directory.
set( test_build_DIR ../../test/cpp/outputs )
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${test_build_DIR})

# Adds the CMakeLists.txt file located in the specified directory
# as a build dependency.
add_subdirectory( # Specifies the directory of the CMakeLists.txt file.
        ${test_DIR}

        # Specifies the directory for the build outputs.
        ${test_build_DIR} )
```

This is the full output of Task :app:buildCMakeDebug[x86_64]

```
> Task :app:buildCMakeDebug[x86_64] FAILED
C/C++: ninja: Entering directory `C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\SoundSculptor\app\.cxx\Debug\5je3e5a3\x86_64'
C/C++: ld.lld: error: unable to find library -latomic
C/C++: ld.lld: error: cannot open C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\lib\clang\16\lib\linux\libclang_rt.builtins-x86_64-android.a: no such file or directory
C/C++: ld.lld: error: unable to find library -l:libunwind.a
C/C++: ld.lld: error: cannot open C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\lib\clang\16\lib\linux\libclang_rt.builtins-x86_64-android.a: no such file or directory
C/C++: ld.lld: error: unable to find library -l:libunwind.a
ld.lld: error: unable to find library -latomic

C/C++: clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
C/C++: ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
ld.lld: error: cannot open C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\lib\clang\16\lib\linux\libclang_rt.builtins-x86_64-android.a: no such file or directory


ld.lld: error: unable to find library -l:libunwind.a

ld.lld: error: cannot open C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\lib\clang\16\lib\linux\libclang_rt.builtins-x86_64-android.a: no such file or directory

ld.lld: error: unable to find library -l:libunwind.a

clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I remove those lines of code from my cmake, it runs the app fine.

Comment: Which subproject are you including? Most likely, exactly that subproject causes the issues you observe.

Comment: I am including a directory with an empty cmakelists.txt

Comment: Wow, restarted my computer and it works now.